# How to (quick) redefine the space between section number and section title in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titletoc

Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16278/10157), I could use `titletoc` (which is want I want to do) and completely redefine the format with

```
\titlecontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above>}
          {<before with label>}{<before without label>}
          {<filler and page>}[<after>]
```

as indicated in the `titletoc` documentation, and to place a `\contentslabel{length}` in the field `<before with label>`. ButIi'm absolutely happy with the style and I just want to modify the space. Is there a way to somehow use `\contentslabel{length}` without redefining the whole `\titlecontents` ?

Comment: An MWE can take you a long way :)

Comment: Include a minimal working example and I will be able to solve your problem. But it depends on the documentclass you use and some other things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spacing - How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the)

Answer (score 4):

The "`\contentslabel`" spacing specifications of ToC entries are governed by `\@dottedtocline`. And, even though [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) allows for global modification of these, it doesn't allow an easy interface for modifying only certain parts of it. As such, here's a work-around: Modify `\@dottedtocline` directly.

For [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

- `\section` (level 1): Indent = `0pt`; label width = `1.5em`
- `\subsection` (level 2): Indent = `1.5em`; label width = `2.3em`
- `\subsubsection` (level 3): Indent = `3.8em`; label width = `3.2em`
- `\paragraph` (level 4): Indent = `7.0em`; label width = `4.1em`
- `\subparagraph` (level 5): Indent = `10.0em`; label width = `5.0em`

For [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

- `\chapter` (level 0): Indent = `0pt`; label width = `1.5em`
- `\section` (level 1): Indent = `1.5em`; label width = `2.3em`
- `\subsection` (level 2): Indent = `3.8em`; label width = `3.2em`
- `\subsubsection` (level 3): Indent = `7.0em`; label width = `4.1em`
- `\paragraph` (level 4): Indent = `10.0em`; label width = `5.0em`
- `\subparagraph` (level 5): Indent = `12.0em`; label width = `6.0em`

Note how the indent of level X is equivalent to the sum of label widths of levels (X-1), (X-2), ... (...except for levels 4 and 5). This allows horizontal alignment between levels in the ToC. So, if you wish to reduce the space of the contents label at the `\section` level in `article` to be only `1em`, you can use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{1.0em}{}{}% Patch \section label width
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.0em}{2.3em}}% Correct \subsection indent
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.3em}{3.2em}}% Correct \subsubsection indent
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{6.5em}{4.1em}}% Correct \paragraph indent
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10.6em}{5em}}% Correct \subparagraph indent
\makeatletter
```

Again, note that the modification is required across all levels below `\section` to ensure that the ToC is properly aligned horizontally.

Finally, similar indentations and widths are included in the LoF and LoT, all at the section level (1) by default. For consistency, you might wish to change these as well, using a similar approach as above. The definitions of interest are

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

in `article`, `book` and `report`.

Ps: The use of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\l@section` is easier that performing a redefinition, since the structure of `\l@section` differs from that of the lower-level `\l@<section>` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `\tableofcontents` by:

```
\begingroup
\let\orignumberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\orignumberline{#1}\kern-1ex}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

You can adjust `1ex` in `\kern-1ex` to any value.